# iOS - Schedule a task - NOT RUNNING state

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, ios9, uilocalnotification

I have some local notifications scheduled and I have to validate a condition before presenting the notification. If the condition doesn't satisfy, I have to cancel the notification i.e. I should not present it.

In iOS, I am aware that we do not have control to local notification when it is delivered (Like Android does). When breaking my head to support for all app states, couple of options comes to mind

1) Schedule another local notification (likely silent notification) 5 minutes before the actual schedule time and validate the condition. For example, if I have to schedule a local notification for 3 hours, I would create 2 local notifications. One, 5 minutes before 3 hours and the next one for 3 hours. But local notification would not wake up the app if app is NOT RUNNING, literally logic fails.

2) Silent push notification - which is the only possible weapon that I have to wake up the app. But server dependency is there.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Can't you validate the condition when you schedule for the local notification?

Comment: The condition is a web API call. There are possibilities that the data could be changed at the server end by the time I receive local notification.

Comment: In that case, using remote notifications sounds like the best approach - the server would do the check before sending the notification.

Comment: FYI- There is no concept called Silent(local notification). We have silent(remote notification), that ll work when the app is in background or foreground.

Comment: Yes. I know. I meant a local notification with no body, no sound, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now (10/05/2016), it is not at all possible.